# How to convert a for loop output from a database into a list using Python?

Tags: python

```
for item in TBL_MAPPING_CONDITIONS:
    if ATCP_IF_ID in item:
        if PK in item:
            TEST1 = item[6]
            OBJECT_NAME = TEST1.split('.')[1]
            TABLE_NAME = [TEST1.split('.')[0]]
            list1 = []
            list1.append(list[TABLE_NAME])
            print(list1)
```

Output:
Product
Customer
Product
Order

Expected Output:
[Product, Customer, Product, Order]

Comment: In your code, define `list1 = []` before for loop! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the list1 declaration out of the loop :

```
list1 = []
for item in TBL_MAPPING_CONDITIONS:
    if ATCP_IF_ID in item:
        if PK in item:
            TEST1 = item[6]
            OBJECT_NAME = TEST1.split('.')[1]
            TABLE_NAME = [TEST1.split('.')[0]]
            
            list1.append(list[TABLE_NAME])

print(list1)
```